# Is it possible to upcast in Room Dao?

Tags: android, android-room

Here's a simple example to explain the question.

```
public interface User {
    long getId();
}

@Entity
public class UserImpl implements User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private final long id;

    public UserImpl(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Dao
public interface UserImplDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM UserImpl")
    List<UserImpl> getAll();
}

@Database(entities = UserImpl.class, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserImplDao userImplDao();
}
```

Is it possible to make UserImplDao return `List<User>` instead of `List<UserImpl>`?

Seems like it should be easy enough but it doesn't compile if I change the return type to `List<User>`.

`error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue and was attempting to find out whether it is supported.

Unfortunately it appears that you cannot have a `Dao` return a supertype but have it construct the subtype.

In my research I found an open issue requesting the ability to do this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78317963